# Create the loading three little dots

Tags: ruby, loading

Hello how can I make the three dot loading (...), so that it does something like this except without making a new line everytime:

Loading

Loading.

Loading...

Loading..

Loading.

and so on:

This is what I came up with, only problem is that I can't remove the dots one by one if loading continues for more than 1.5 seconds.

```
puts "Sending"
sleep(0.5)
print "."
sleep(0.5)
print "."
sleep(0.5)
print "."
```

Hopefully I am clear enough.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at `"\r"` escape sequence. It puts the cursor at the beginning of the current line, so you can write it over.

Comment: Combine @SergioTulentsev's advice with the modulo operator (%), which gets a remainder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
10.times do |i|   
    print "Sending." +  ("." * (i % 3)) + "  \r"    
    $stdout.flush   
    sleep(0.5)
end
```

So, how does this work?

```
10.times do |i|
```

Repeat the following code 10 times, with the variable `i` indicating the current iteration (0, 1, 2, 3, 4...)

```
    print "Sending." +  ("." * (i % 3)) + "  \r"
```

Print the phrase "Sending." followed by a couple of things:

- `("." * (i % 3))` repeats ("multiplies") the string `"."` several times, specifically `i % 3`, which is the remainder of `i` when it's divided by 3. So when `i` is 7, `i % 3` is 1.
- `"\r"` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line *without* making a new line. If you think of a typewriter, it's like returning the carriage (the bit that types) to the beginning of the line so that you can type over the same line again. It's a **carriage return**.

  ```
  $stdout.flush
  ```

Make sure the data prints.

```
    sleep(0.5)
```

Sleep for half a sec.

Comment: Perfect this works and does exactly what I want it to do. However I do not exactly understand how the code works. Would you mind explaining it to me? Thank you.

Comment: I added an explanation. Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [`$stdout.flush`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-flush):

```
def loading number_of
  number_of.times do |t|
    print "Sending#{'.' * (t % 4)}   \r"
    $stdout.flush
    sleep 0.5
  end
end
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/wor/8)

Comment: This is missing the part with "removing the dots". repl.it is nice, though.

Comment: @undur_gongor: thanks, but it appears to be pretty useless in this case though.